Issues with saving and loading a model using tensorflow
I created a simple cnn model that uses mobilenet as a pretrained model. After training I want to save the model for later use but I am unable to save it in HDF5 format. After saving it in keras unable to load the model either.
I tried saving the model using
    model.save("model.h5")

I got the error :
ValueError: Unable to synchronously create dataset (name already exists)
Obviously I have tried with different names but none of them worked.
After saving the model as in the .keras format, when I try to load the model I am getting the error
Kernel shape must have the same length as input,
Model:
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
mobilenet = MobileNet(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), weights = 'imagenet', include_top=False)
for layers in mobilenet.layers:
    layers.trainable = False
model.add(mobilenet)

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1024,kernel_size =  2, padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax"))


I fixed it, it was an issue with the version of tensorflow. TensorFlow 16.1.1 has a bunch of bugs.
